# Need to put markers on a papervision3d model (esphere) on execution time (flash/flex)

Tags: apache-flex, flash, papervision3d

I'm using papervision3d to load a 3D sphere with the world texture on a Flash project. I want to know how can I put a marker on the model given a coordinate? Example: two angles, and with marker I refer to a simple movieclip or similar. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to convert to from spherical coordinates(uses 2 angles and a radius) into cartesian coordinates(x,y,z).

[image: Papervision Geocoding]
<sub>(source: [psyked.co.uk](http://www.psyked.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/createworld.jpg))</sub>

Luckily there is [a nice article](https://www.adobe.com/inspire-archive/june2008/articles/article2/index.html) out there that explains this using Papervision.

Someone else also recorded a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9e-0ECqsfTU) tutorial.

HTH

Comment: This is a similar answer I provided earlier except it uses geometry to map a location rather than storing graphical markers on another layer.  I'm assuming the author is looking for a solution where he can put multiple markers and not have Papervision3D parse a high number of DisplayObject3d objects so I suggest storing rasterized markers.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to place another sphere at the same origin with a radius slightly larger with a BitmapMaterial.  Then you can draw directly on the BitmapMaterial according to a location mapped from the sphere.  Where you're mapping spherical coordinates to a specific (u,v) on your bitmap.

Your "two angles" would be your spherical coordinates and the (u,v) coordinates would be the top-left relative coordinates on the bitmap.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was voted down since I have a current project that was launched a couple of months ago with this same solution.  If the solution is unclear please state so.